# Is it plagiarism if I don't mention where I found a quotation originally?

Tags: graduate-school, etiquette, plagiarism, research-misconduct, quotation

Say `author A` writes on `Topic B` and in this context uses `quotation C` which is not from the same field and appears highly original in `Topic B`. I then read this article, and I am myself writing on `Topic B`. I find the quote so useful or relevant, that I quote it myself.

Am I obliged to mention where I found the quote (namely in `author A`)? Or can I just use the quote? Where are the boundaries here, what do you think is acceptable, what is not? Also, if it is not ethical, that's one thing - but is it also plagiarism?

PS: If anyone has a good title for this sort of question, please feel free to edit. Not sure how to name this.

Comment: Why would you want to *not* quote `author A`?

Comment: I would not mind to do that. My note taking system is sometimes getting a bit out of hand, and I am worried that at some point in the future I will accidentally do something like this without realising. I might jot down a quote, and then later find it again & use it, - and then realise that I should not have only taken down that quote, but also should have noted where & in which context I found that quote. Well, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You can search for a string in your computer files or on the internet.  For the former, I find "File Locator Lite" helpful. // If you slip up very occasionally -- well, nobody's perfect.  But if you can try to be more careful in noting the source of each quote you put in your notes, that would be best.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, this might be very close to plagiarism, but without knowing the details this is hard to tell. The litmus test is this: consider you are `author A` and somebody else does that: what would you feel?

To be on the save side, just give credit to `author A` for introducing the `quotation C` in the context of `topic B` (but not more). There is no harm done in this way.